# Ability to pass different argument signatures as function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have two functions `article.getByCustomerAndCategory` (that takes two parameters) and `article.getById` (that takes one).

```
function  getArticle ({ customer_id, category_id, article_id }: Partial<Article>): Article {
    if (customer_id && category_id) {
        return article.getByCustomerAndCategory({
            customer_id,
            category_id,
        });
    }
    if (article_id) {
        return article.getById({
            article_id
        });
    }
    throw new Error('invalid argument');
};
```

Also tried:

```
type articleInput = { customer_id, category_id } | { article_id };

function  getArticle (input: articleInput): Article {
    if (input.customer_id && input.category_id) {
        return serviceRecurrence.get({
            customer_id,
            category_id,
        });
    }
    if (input.article_id) {
        return serviceRecurrence.getById({
            article_id
        });
    }
    throw new Error('invalid argument');
};
```

I am looking to combine the two into one function that can take either `customer_id` and `category_id` or just `article_id`. The return types are all the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sound to me like you can merge it in to just a single interface that you pass in to the function. You then just check what the interface contains and go.

Comment: Have a single `article_or_customer_id` parameter, whose semantic value is determined by the presence of the second parameter. You don't really have a question in your question by the way.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried something liked that as well, updated above, however it complains because the presence of all the properties are within the function.

Comment: I guess you are looking for function [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Comment: @JonasWilms since the return type is the same and there is just one parameter I don't think overloads are necessary, and the part OP seems to be struggling with is the actual implementation IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was not too far off. Using a union to represent the two kinds of parameters that can be passed to the function is a good idea. The part you are missing is a type guard to narrow the type of the `input` parameter to one of the union members:

```
// Assumed declarations  Types
interface Article {
    customer_id: number, category_id: number
}
let serviceRecurrence: {
    get(p: {
        customer_id: number, category_id: number
    }): Article
    getById(p: {
        article_id: number
    }): Article
}
type articleInput = { customer_id: number, category_id: number } | { article_id: number };

// The function 
function  getArticle (input: articleInput): Article {
    if ('article_id' in input) { // in typeguard
        return serviceRecurrence.getById({
            ... input // input is { article_id: number } and we can use a spread operator to create the input for getById
        });
    }
    else  {
        return serviceRecurrence.get({
            ... input // input is { customer_id: number, category_id: number } and we can use a spread operator to create the input for get
        });
    }
    throw new Error('invalid argument');
};
```